# Issue Importing Models to Diffusion Bee

Tags: macos, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

When trying to import a Protogen model (.ckpt file type) to Diffusion Bee, I keep getting this error:

Error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "convert_model.py", line 28, in 
KeyError: 'state_dict'
[83158] Failed to execute script 'convert_model' due to unhandled exception!

The model should import without issue.